# Does integer promotion occur after explicit cast?

Tags: c

```
char port = 0xa5;
```

I wonder how the expression below evaluated according to standard.

```
(uint8_t) (~port) >> 4
```

Does left argument first converted to uint8_t and then promoted to int or vice versa?

Comment: The cast operator has a higher precedence than `>>`. So it "works" first.

Comment: So there is a undefined behaviour due to signed shift, right?

Comment: Ok, you should note that there are *three* different operations happen here. `~` is an operation that is performing promotions too. There is no undefined behavior here. Implementation defined - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casts have [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than bit shifts, so the cast should be executed first.

I also found [this resource](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) which explains the need for the cast:

> In this compliant solution, the bitwise complement of port is
> converted back to 8 bits. Consequently, result_8 is assigned the
> expected value of 0x0aU.
>
> ```
> uint8_t port = 0x5a;
> uint8_t result_8 = (uint8_t) (~port) >> 4;
> ```

Note that the *complement* is converted to 8 bits, not the final result of the entire expression.

Comment: I too, confused because of that source.

Comment: We probably ran into the same misunderstanding of what was written there. Please see my edit.

Comment: So we are safe because we got a nonnegative value at the left after promotion. Thank you.